# Create and call a function on a class?

Tags: objective-c

Hello good people of Stackoverflow, i'm trying to make a function that gets a number of seconds and then create a local alert, here is what i have:

I created a class named manualtimer.h this is a Nsobject class.

In the manualTimer.h i have the following code:

```
-(void)tempoAlerta:(NSTimeInterval *)otempo;
```

In the manualTimer.M i have the following code:

```
-(void)tempoAlerta:(NSTimeInterval *)otempo {


    UIApplication* myapp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UILocalNotification* localnote = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];

    localnote.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:*otempo];
    localnote.alertBody = @"Nice Alert";
    localnote.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    NSMutableArray *notifications = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [notifications addObject:localnote];
    myapp.scheduledLocalNotifications = notifications;

}
```

In my viewcontroller, i imported the manualTimer.h, but for some reason a cannot call the function tempoAlerta()

any ideas? xCode show no errors?

Answer (score 0):

you must to instantiate a object of that class

```
manualTimer *obj = [[manualTimer alloc] init];
```

and then call that function

```
[obj tempoalerta:otempo];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have in your example code is defining a **Method** not a function. Functions are c style `void anExampleFunction(int anArgument)` and cannot be defined on objective-c classes.

How are you calling the method?

Your call should look something like this:

```
ManualTimer *timer = [ManualTimer new];
[timer temoAlerta:10];
```

Please look at this documentation for more information:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007594-CH1-SW11